# Automatic refresh data using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically refresh data within a table every 5 seconds. I already tried the `setInterval` function.

```
function ref() {
    setInterval(function(){
        if(!$('input:focus').length){
            $('#tab').load("index.php #tab");
        }
    }, 5000); 
}
```

It worked until I tried to make the table more clear to read and add that function:

```
function rroz() {
    var h = 0;
    var kn = 0;
    var mh = 0;
    var mkn = 0;

    $(".kname").each(function(){
        kn = kn+1;
    });

    $(".mkname").each(function(){
        mkn = mkn+1;
    });

    for(var i=1;i<=kn;i++){
        if(h <= $("#kname"+i).height()){
            h = $("#kname"+i).height();
        }
    }

    for(var i=1;i<=mkn;i++){
        if(mh <= $("#mkname"+i).height()){
            mh = $("#mkname"+i).height();
        }
    }

    console.log('h='+h+'&mh='+mh);

    for(var i=1;i<=kn;i++){
        $("#kname"+i).height(h);
    }

    for(var i=1;i<=mkn;i++){
        $("#mkname"+i).height(mh);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to refresh data on table?

Comment: what is error of `rroz` function? check your console

Comment: First of all. Do not use interval as you could never know if sometimes your load will take longer then 5s. In that case you will end in an endless refresh. Use timeout and start a new timeout when the load and refresh is finished.

Comment: Also I don't like it to design html with javascript. You should try to use only css to make your table nice looking

Comment: Thanks @ClausBönnhoff ! Change to setTimeout helps. And I use design in js because it is easier way to make it equal.

Comment: This might be only the case because you lack of css knowledge ;)